# R Studio: Opening an RMD file that contains a report, and another of code, but there is no content. Am I missing a package?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a report sent to me in the format of an RMD file. Another RMD that contains the code. However, all that I see are empty files when opened. Im using anaconda: Rstudio 3 version 1.1.456 (is this outdated?)

Unless there is a script to open the file?

Answer (score 0):

The [.Rmd format](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_intro.html) is a particular flavor of markdown so you can open the file with any plain text editor to verify that it is not empty and indeed has the code inside.

Comment: I tried google colab but i just get an error

Comment: If i knit the file i just get an error "error in library(reshape) : there is no package called 'reshape'...

Comment: Install reshape (`install.packages("reshape")`) and any other required packages and then try knitting the Rmd file again.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to my problem: For anyone trying to open an Rmd file in the future with similar circumstances.. open the file, while open, Go into "file - Reopen with encoding - UTF-8".